# groovy get http parse json/xml

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Hey i have this talk to do:

- Use solr api, use this url: `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=tree`
- Get the answer via json/xml, deserialize it to a map objects

What is the best way to do that? I would like some hints on this.
Thanks in advanced, RR

Ps. i searched for it in here, but i found examples too complex to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( new URL( 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=tree' ).text )
```

Get you to where you want to be?

Right, so this is Grails prior to 2.0, so can't use `JsonSlurper` as that needs Groovy 1.8+

Can you try:

```
def json = grails.converters.JSON.parse( new URL( 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=tree' ).text )
```

Comment: @recoInrelax any luck? Let me know of any problems :-)

Comment: this import: import groovy.json.JsonSlurper nit working idk why

Comment: @recoInrelax which version of Groovy? [`JsonSlurper`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) has only been in since Groovy 1.8

Comment: @recoInrelax Download it [from here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download), and alter your path to point to it?  I have a symlink (OS X/Linux) on my machine, so I just have `~/Applications/groovy` in my path, and can re-point it to whichever version I need to test

Comment: @recoInrelax Same error?  You might have both on your path, and be still using 1.7.5...  Try `println GroovySystem.version` and see what it says?

Comment: prints 1.7.5 . but if i type in cmd(windows): 'groovy -v' it says 1.8.4

Comment: Are you running the scripts in an IDE then?  Maybe that needs updating?

Comment: yes. im doing a web-app in graisl, and using groovy in the controllers. idk if this have anything to do, but in libraries it says: groovy 1.6.4

Comment: @recoInrelax Oh right...  You managed to avoid mentioning this was inside grails in the whole of your question and discussion...  Inside Grails, you're stuck with whatever version that version of Grails is using... Grails 1.3.7 uses Groovy 1.7.8, Grails 2.0 uses Groovy 1.8+.  Nothing you can do about that...  Updated my answer with a possible solution (now we have found out this information)

Comment: No such property: grails for class: xxx.abcController

Comment: @recoInrelax with `def json = grails.converters.JSON.parse( new URL( 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=tree' ).text )`?  I missed the `JSON` bit with my initial update, but added it in 24 mins ago

Comment: ok. so json is a map. how can i get single attributes? would it be json[1].attributename?=

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5459/discussion-between-recoinrelax-and-tim-yates)

Comment: @recoInrelax without example json or an actual description of what you want to do, this is not going to be easy...  I cannot see what you have, I don't know what you want, and you haven't said what you have tried, or why that doesn't work...

Comment: ok. so about this question, this is actually working which i'll accept the asnwer. join me in chat plz

Comment: How will it work when HTTP response is not plain ASCII ? new URL(...).text uses default system encoding, but not specified in the request

Comment: @TimurYusupov I guess if you're default system encoding is not set to handle the encoding being returned, you'll have to go the [long way round](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4555254/6509) as you would with Java (but that code can be groovified as well, to be shorter and more clear)

Comment: @tim_yates, actually the example you given uses hardcoded UTF-8 charset to decode the reponse.
If there is need to use fixed UTF-8 charset, you can just use

    new URL( 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=tree' ).text("UTF-8")

But neither example for your link nor .text("UTF-8") does not take into account charset specified in response content-type heading, which could vary and depends on server side implementation.

To handle this it is needed either implement parsing content-type heading value to get charset from it or use some library like http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder.